# symfony2 rest api with separated client and end user security

Tags: api, security, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I'm building a REST API on symfony2 and I'm not sure what would be the best way to manage different security levels.

- Unauthenticated clients (apps or websites that have no permission to reach the API data) can't get (get, put, post, etc) data from the API
- Authenticated clients will be able to request some data from the API but not user related data.
- On the other hand, end users need to be logged in somehow to access some private resources from the API.

For example, `api/v1/philosophies` would list all the phylosophies to an authenticated client. Unregistered end users could see the list: 'idealism, realism, existencialism, ...'.
But end users would need to be authorized (registered and logged) to access their favorite phylosophies through `api/v1/user/{userID}/favorites`.

I've been reading and testing stuff with FOSUserBundle, FOSRestBundle and FOSOAuthServerBundle but all the information i find has the users always logged in order to get the token and the whole api is protected both by client and by users.

Any idea?

Some light?

please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOSRest and FOSAuth will work fine for what you need, it just looks like you will need to change the way your access is defined in security.yml.  The only reason you always have to be logged in to access resources, is because the resources are protected.  If you have a resource that you want to allow anonymous access to, then make that entry in security.yml, something like this:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/v1/pilosophies$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/v1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

This would make `/api/v1/pilosophies` accessible without logging in, but all other resources would still be protected.  you can read more about this in the docs [Securing specific url patterns](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-specific-url-patterns)

In the end, you are the one that decides what resources are protected or not. FOSOAuth has nothing to do with that decision.

Comment: So what would be the flow for clients in order to use the api? get the token through /oauth/v2/auth // /oauth/v2/token on initialize and then use the api. Whenever the end user tries to access information from a protected part of the api, the api would return a login form¿??¿ I understand the api should return an unauthorized access error or something like that and the user should log in somehow. I thought the user would login through oauth also. i'm a bit confused.

Comment: if the user gets an oAuth token, then he is already logged in, so there is no need for a login form.  As long as he has a token, he should be able to access any protected part of the api.

Comment: mh... I think i'm getting all wrong then. How do i know which websites or apps have access to the API? i thought i would use oauth for that too.

Comment: in order for an app or website to have access to your api, you have to give them a `client_id` and `client_secret`.  So you control who has access to your api.

Comment: So the apps or website won't use oAuth and the end user will?

Comment: I don't understand your last question.

Comment: well, what i'm trying to understand is how to differentiate between apps and websites (which would have a client_id and secret) and end users (that have username and password). I see two different authorization processes here and i don't know to manage them separately, oAuth would be for both of them? oAuth only for clients, or only for end users?

Comment: oAuth2 has several 'grant_types'.  Read [this blog post](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/16/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-and-terminology/), it will help you understand the different oAuth concepts, and is a great tutorial for setting up the FOSOAuthServerBundle

Comment: looks like what you need is the scopes setup: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/dealing_with_scopes.md